# How to pass bearer token to make Yelp API call with URLSessoin

Tags: ios, swift, api, bearer-token, yelp

U P D A T E D... The function with what works!
I would like to incorporate the yelp api into an app but can't successfully pass my authorization token on the URL string.   Do I need to do something to connect the URLRequest to the URLSessoin call and its not using the header?  Maybe the key value pairs is wrong? The below function returns:

```
error =     {
        code = "TOKEN_MISSING";
        description = "An access token must be supplied in order to use this endpoint.";
    };
```

I was able to use postman to get the yelp API call working, but only by clicking the "Header" section on postman and putting in Bearer and then my yelp key.  I googled around a bit and found some links that indicate that you can add a header to the URLSession that I assume would work the way postman does but I haven't been able to get it to work.

I know there are some githubs with yelp API repos but I am trying to not install a large set of code that I don't understand into my app, when all I want is the JSON that I can see is coming through on postman.  Can anyone help me understand how I would edit code similar to the Here example below so that I can get the Authorization/Bearer that yelp requires?

```
func getYelp() {
        let appSecret = "Bearer <YELP APIKEY>"
        let link = "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?latitude=37.786882&longitude=-122.399972"
        if let url = URL(string: link) {
            // Set headers
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.setValue("Accept-Language", forHTTPHeaderField: "en-us")
            request.setValue(appSecret, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

            print("Attempting to get places around location from Yelp")
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                } else {
                    if let urlContent = data {
                        do {
                            let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject // Added "as anyObject" to fix syntax error in Xcode 8 Beta 6
                            print("Printing all JSON/n/n//n--------------------------")
                            print(jsonResult)
                            print("Printing from results/n/n//n--------------------------")

                            if let description = ((jsonResult["search"] as? NSDictionary)?["context"] as? NSDictionary)?["href"] as? String {

                            } else {
                                print("JSON pull failed/n/n//n--------------------------")
                            }

                        } catch {
                            print("JSON Processing Failed/n/n//n--------------------------")
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        } else {
            resultLabel.text = "Couldn't get results from Here"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up between the headers and the url, you need to set your headers correctly

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/around?at=37.776169%2C-122.421267&app_id=\(app_id)&app_code=\(app_code)") {
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    // Set headers
    request.setValue("Accept-Language", forHTTPHeaderField: "en-us")
    request.setValue("Authorization", forHTTPHeaderField: "Bearer " + token // Token here)

    print("Attempting to get places around location")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        // ...
```

Comment: I added the code you recommended but it still says no token was provided.  I also tried using "with: url" and "with: request", is it possible there is something else I am missing?  I updated the question with the current full function.

Comment: You need to check the documentation for required headers

Comment: Figured it out... the name value pair arguments were just reversed... 
   request.setValue(appSecret, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have an api with "https://google.com" (this is just an example with fake keys)
and an api key that is "ApiKey: 92927839238293d92d98d98d92".

You would then take this information and do this.

```
let uri = URL(string:"https://google.com")
    if let unwrappedURL = uri {
      var request = URLRequest(url: unwrappedURL)request.addValue("92927839238293d92d98d98d92", forHTTPHeaderField: "ApiKey")
let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    // you should put in error handling code, too
    if let data = data {
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            // HERE'S WHERE YOUR DATA IS
            print(json)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
dataTask.resume()
}
```

Please remember that you would replace the google.com with your GET address and the APIKey header with your own api key values.
Also, this will print out all the JSON like in PostMan.
If this works for you, then I also have a link on accessing the JSON Objects.